# Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'kafkaTemplate' defined in class path resource

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, java-17

Upgraded springboot version 2.1.18.RELEASE to 2.7.16 and java 8 to java 17
Project build completed successfully but I am getting below error when i am deploying.

{"@timestamp":"2023-10-13T09:44:41.354Z","@version":"1","message":"Application run failed","logger_name":"org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication","thread_name":"main","level":"ERROR","level_value":40000,"stack_trace":"org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.KafkaAnnotationDrivenConfiguration': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.KafkaAnnotationDrivenConfiguration]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'kafkaTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/kafka/KafkaAutoConfiguration.class]: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate] from ClassLoader [org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@28c97a5]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:310)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:291)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1372)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955)\n\tat org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:921)\n\tat org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292)\n\tat com.cemdo.reporting.dashboard.info.ReportingDashboardInfoConfig.main(ReportingDashboardInfoConfig.java:55)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65)\nCaused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.KafkaAnnotationDrivenConfiguration]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'kafkaTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/kafka/KafkaAutoConfiguration.class]: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate] from ClassLoader [org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@28c97a5]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:224)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:117)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:306)\n\t... 27 common frames omitted\nCaused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'kafkaTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/kafka/KafkaAutoConfiguration.class]: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate] from ClassLoader [org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@28c97a5]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:597)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1391)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory$DependencyObjectProvider.getIfUnique(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:2074)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.KafkaAnnotationDrivenConfiguration.(KafkaAnnotationDrivenConfiguration.java:93)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Unknown Source)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:211)\n\t... 29 common frames omitted\nCaused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate] from ClassLoader [org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@28c97a5]\n\tat org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:485)\n\tat org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithLocalMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:321)\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.buildPersistenceMetadata(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:417)\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findPersistenceMetadata(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:388)\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:335)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1116)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594)\n\t... 44 common frames omitted\nCaused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/ConsumerGroupMetadata\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)\n\tat org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:467)\n\t... 50 common frames omitted\nCaused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerGroupMetadata\n\tat java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:151)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)\n\t... 54 common frames omitted\n","appname":"dashboard-info"}

i have tried adding the dependencies~

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>


    <properties>
        <swagger.codegen.version>3.0.34</swagger.codegen.version>
        <spring-restdocs.version>2.0.5.RELEASE</spring-restdocs.version>
        <springframework.boot.version>2.7.16</springframework.boot.version>
        <testcontainers.version>1.17.1</testcontainers.version>
        <jackson.version>2.13.3</jackson.version>
        <tomcat-embed.version>9.0.80</tomcat-embed.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat-embed.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat-embed.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat-embed.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-annotations-api</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat-embed.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
            <version>4.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger.codegen.v3</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-codegen</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger.codegen.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.agileware</groupId>
            <artifactId>smartunit</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.stefanbirkner</groupId>
            <artifactId>system-lambda</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>testcontainers</artifactId>
            <version>${testcontainers.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Postgres -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>${testcontainers.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
             </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/pwsh</directory>
                <targetPath>pwsh</targetPath>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.9.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
                <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.13</version>
                <configuration>
                    <useMavenSettingsForAuth>true</useMavenSettingsForAuth>
                    <repository>${docker.image.repository}</repository>
                    <tag>${docker.image.version}</tag>
                    <buildArgs>
                        <JAR_FILE>${project.build.finalName}-exec.jar</JAR_FILE>
                    </buildArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
                <artifactId>fabric8-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <profile>raw</profile>
                    <!-- Ignore any services recreation if they exist (which can cause ClusterIP addresses to change for services)  -->
                    <ignoreServices>false</ignoreServices>
                    <registry>${docker.image.prefix}</registry>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                        <artifactId>surefire-junit4</artifactId>
                        <version>3.1.2</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/*IntegrationTest.java</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*IntegrationTest.java</include>
                    </includes>
                    <argLine>-Xmx512m</argLine>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: You, somehow, have an old version of the `kafka-clients` jar on your class path. Use Maven to look at the dependency tree to see where it is coming from. Boot 2.7 is compatible with spring-kafka 2.8 or 2.9 (2.9.12 preferred, with `kafka-clients` 3.2.3 or later).

Comment: @GaryRussell -- Thank you very much. Changing the version of kafka-clients resolved my issue.